# Dapr pub-sub connection refused

Tags: asp.net-core, azureservicebus, dapr, azure-container-apps

I have an endpoint wired up to subscribe to an Azure Service Bus Topic.  Something like this:

```cs
[Topic("my-component", "my-topic")]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyResponse>> DoIt(CloudEvent cloudEvent)
{ ... }
```

Sometimes, the processing is failing.  It just seems to stop in the middle of processing.  From stdout I see this from the sidecar `daprd` container:

> time="2023-02-02T17:13:30.699870594Z" level=error msg="App handler returned an error for message 73b53011f9b54ec4a1563d790fa3db99 on topic blah-topic: error from app channel while sending pub/sub event to app: dial tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused" app_id=my-app instance=my-app--5deqq11-59465485d4c-n52rv scope=dapr.contrib type=log ver=1.9.5-msft-2

What doesn't make sense is the `connection refused`.  I'm subscribing not publishing.  Connection to what is refused?

It seems like this is happening on long-running requests so timeouts come to mind but that doesn't add up w/ `connection refused`.

What does that error mean?  Is it a red herring or related to the failure of some of my messages?

Comment: [where the error is thrown](https://github.com/dapr/dapr/blob/b74b7d92b0821149bd61ed7f12f8c86f1e5972a9/pkg/runtime/runtime.go#L2146) in dapr code base (I think)

Comment: `daprd` is calling your `DoIt()` method over http (`127.0.0.1:80`) and sometimes it's getting 'connection refused'.